# Pastebot Mac software says Disabled in menu

Tags: macos, iphone, menu-bar, copy-paste, ipad

I don't use Pastebot on this computer very often, but it has worked previously without difficulty.  Today, the menu shows "Disabled..." in grey text, and Pastebot doesn't allow me to copy & paste between Mac and device.

[image: Pastebot Mac menu]

- I downloaded the Mac preference pane and installed it again.  This seemed to work OK, although there were two messages about "... is from an unidentified developer", to which I said Open.
- I followed the Pastebot process to pair my new iPad 4, and this seemed to work OK: the numeric password showed up on the Mac, and I typed it.  But I still see Disabled in the Mac menu bar, and it doesn't seem to sync.
- This was working previously with my iPhone 4S, but it doesn't now.
- Pastebot is turned on in the Mac pref pane.
- The Firewall is turned off on the Mac.
- The Pastebot support site doesn't seem to mention this possibility.
- I can't see any relevant messages in Console.app.
- Everything else about the Mac, iPad, iPhone seems to be working OK.

Any ideas how I might get Pastebot working again?

Comment: Soo... What's the problem?

Comment: @Undo Sorry... I've tried to clarify: see my edits.

Comment: Much better. Can't help, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the answer was right in front of me, but I didn't see it.

To fix this problem, choose the first item in the menu: "Enable Pastebot Sync".

Duh!